# How to reset default permissions for / in ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I ran the following commands in terminal

sudo -s

chmod 754 /

Now the system does not start in normal mode. However, I can luckily run root shell prompt from recovery mode. As I have a lot of useful data, so I don't want to reinstall the OS. I need to restore the default user permissions through root shell prompt.

Comment: From recovery root prompt, try `chmod 755 /`

Comment: Yes it works now! :) please post this as an answer so that I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on recovery root prompt, please do `chmod 755 /`. The system needed the execute bit for all users to boot correctly.